# developing a real-time betting engine using redis / sinatra / thin

Tags: nginx, sinatra, redis, thin

I'm currently building a real-time betting engine using redis / thin / sinatra. A pre-signup is available here at http://www.thematchfixer.com

I am using some logic on how betting odds are generated and how they change in real-time. That all seems to work fine (in any case this is just a game and no real-money is involved..so a few wrong odds here and there don't make much of a difference). What I'm getting stuck with is the idea of having a pub/sub implementation using the current technology stack (redis / nginx / thin / sinatra). People suggested that I should be using nodejs or erlang, but because of the learning curve and lack of time, I don't want to try them out right now. Is there any way how I can achieve Comet over my current technology stack (and use the redis pub/sub out of the box) ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think what you are looking for is Cramp, its been recently released, it is a ruby framework based on asynch requests. You have a great explanation and first steps here:

[Introducing Cramp](http://m.onkey.org/introducing-cramp?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+monkeyonrails+%28m.onkey+on+rails%29&utm_content=Google+Reader)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet, but there's Faye (Node and Ruby compatible):

http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby.html